# Combining an IF statement with a SEARCH and subtraction operation

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

I need to search in a column for the word "complete" and if it doesn't exist then I need to subtract a date in another column from today (TODAY()). I have several fields that do not have any values so I'm also doing a check for NULL fields. This is my formula:

> IF(AND(SEARCH(M30,"complete"),O30<>""),"*",O30-TODAY())

(Column M is string of text and column O is a date.)

When I run this formula I'm getting a #VALUE error so I assume something needs to be typecast.

I don't think it will matter for this particular question but I'm using Excel 2013.

Comment: *I need to search in a column* ... do you want to look for "complete" in an entire column set? Or just one cell? Because the text you wrote and the formula imply two different things.

Comment: Yeah you're right, sorry. I'm trying to search in one cell. So M30, then M31, then M32, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the search term is not found the formula will produce an error. So you have to check for an instance of an error to see if it's found or not.

This formula should work:

```
=IF(AND(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH(M30,"complete"))),O30<>""),"*",O30-TODAY())
```

*N.B.* - Bear in mind that the `Search` function as you wrote it may actually be reversed. Depending on your needs, you may need to write it as `SEARCH("complete",M30)`

Comment: Could that [SEARCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SEARCH-function-F79EF0B8-0991-4FC1-93B0-627F019A69E3) have its parameters reversed?

Comment: @jeeped - I thought so at first as well, and even mentioned it in my original post, but decided to not say anything because technically it can still work :) I do think it's worth noting in case the OP didn't intend this.

Comment: Thanks Scott, that did it! I did have to swap the SEARCH parameters around, otherwise it was just giving me -7, but that certainly fixed me up. 

Thanks again for the assistance.